# XYZ to LAB Excel VB Script

Tags: excel, math, vba

I am having some issues with the below VBA Macro. Can someone help me figure out where I have messed up?

The calculation is referenced here http://www.brucelindbloom.com/

```
Public Function LAB_to_XYZ_X(L As Double, A As Double, B As Double) As Double

Dim fx As Double, fx_cubed As Double
Dim fy As Double, fy_cubed As Double
Dim fz As Double, fz_cubed As Double

fy = (L + 16) / 116
fy_cubed = fy * fy * fy
fx = fy + A / 500
fx_cubed = fx * fx * fx
fz = fy - B / 200
fz_cubed = fz * fz * fz

Const LAB_EPSILON = (216 / 24389)
Const LAB_KAPPA = (24389 / 27)

Dim yr As Double, xr As Double, zr As Double

If L > LAB_KAPPA * LAB_EPSILON Then
    yr = fy_cubed
Else:
    yr = L / LAB_KAPPA
End If

If fx_cubed > LAB_EPSILON Then
    xr = fx_cubed
Else:
    xr = (fx * 116 - 16) / LAB_KAPPA
End If

If fz_cubed > LAB_EPSILON Then
    xr = f_zcubed
Else:
    xr = (fx * 116 - 16) / LAB_KAPPA
End If

LAB_to_XYZ_X = xr * D50_WHITE_REF_X
' Y = yr * D50_WHITE_REF_Y
' Z = zr * D50_WHITE_REF_Z

End Function
```

Comment: What, specifically, are the issues you are having?  What is your input, actual output and desired output?

Comment: Also, if you put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, you will get a lot of help when running it.  You should also check `Require Variable Declaration` under `Tools/Options` so that will be automatically placed whenever you insert a module in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There are two conditions, but in the end, there is an error that is determined by the last one.

```
If fx_cubed > LAB_EPSILON Then
    xr = fx_cubed
Else:
    xr = (fx * 116 - 16) / LAB_KAPPA
End If

If fz_cubed > LAB_EPSILON Then '<~~ xr determined by last condition 
    xr = f_zcubed
Else:
    xr = (fx * 116 - 16) / LAB_KAPPA
End If
```